# Nested if-else vs if-else?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, nested

I'm confused on what is meant by "nested if-else statements", compared to if-else if statements.

The following question asks to use it instead of if-else statements but I can't figure out how.

```java
if (playerThrow == ROCK && computerThrow == ROCK) {
    System.out.println("Its a draw!");
} else if (playerThrow == ROCK && computerThrow == PAPER) {
    System.out.println("Computer wins!");
} else if (playerThrow == ROCK && computerThrow == SCISSORS) {
    System.out.println("Player wins!");
} /* ... */
```

[Code is from my textbook (I messed up), else I would have posted mine, sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqIeF.png)

Comment: Ik its a noob question

Comment: We were all noobs once @Drew...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question a bit? We (most of the time) *don't* accept "codn-mages". Please write it directly into the question. Also, links are likely to be broken over time, so better of just using them for reference. Anyway, we're here to help you ;).

Comment: @KemyLand I will thank you

Comment: @Drew: Heh, I wrote "codn-mages", but it was "code-images"...

Comment: @KemyLand Fixed it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between nested and cascaded if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534576/what-is-the-difference-between-nested-and-cascaded-if-else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested if/else means a heirachy so..

```
if($something == true){
    if($something_else == true){
    } else {
    }
} else { // $something == false
    if($something_else == true){
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but... wasn't the OP's code in Java?

Comment: That makes zero difference, nested is nested regardless of language, the process is the same. Syntax is similar too.

Comment: @DanWhite crap sorry clicked it accidentally

Comment: @DanWhite thanks for the help Ill press solved when the 6 minutes is up

Comment: @Drew Great! Glad it helped (even if it is Java)!

Comment: @DanWhite: Of course that makes no reason for a down-vote (actually, the question should be language-agnostic), but I'm stating that's a probable reason for a downvoter to, well... downvote. Downvotes without a respective, explanatory comment usually implies that the downvoter him/herself knows that doing so is just sort of trolling...

Answer (score 2):

A `nested if statement` is essentially a series of `if statements` within each other like so...

```
if (<condition>)
{
    if (<condition>)
    {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

`If-else if statements` make using multiple conditions cleaner and easier to read, all being on the same level, like so:

```
if (<condition 1>)
{
    ...
}
else if (<condition 2>)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

﻿

1. Nested if()...else statements take more execution time (they are slower) in comparison to an else if()... ladder.
2. The nested if()...else statements check all the inner conditional statements once the outer conditional if() statement is satisfied.
   whereas the else if()... ladder will stop condition testing once any of the if() or the else if() conditional statements are true.